# Can "ditto" be similar to "also" and "as well as"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference, adverbs

First definition from Learner's dictionary says **ditto** is *used to say that whatever you have said about one person or thing is also true of another person or thing*

> E.g.
>
> - He is good at baseball, **ditto** at golf.

Can this word be substituted for *also* or *as well as* in this context?

- He is good at baseball, **also** at golf.
- He is good at baseball, **as well as** at golf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main use of *ditto* is in lists, to save yourself the trouble of writing the same thing out in full each time when only a few words are different.

> 10 white cotton handkerchiefs
>
> 10 blue ditto

often expressed by the symbol " (the 'ditto mark').

It can be used in informal speech to mean that what you have said about one thing applies to another, but in your example *also* or *as well as* would be better.

Comment: When I started office work in 1968 (as a summer job) I was taught to use two commas on the line ,, with a typewriter as a ditto mark, or alternatively two slashes // - I see there is a Unicode character〃(middle height of the line), but I also see everyone uses double quotes at the top of the line these days.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly - you can't put "ditto" in place of the word "also" in every situation.

"Ditto" isn't something that is meant to be said or written - it is the name of an annotation in a list to denote a repetition of what has been written before.

Saying, or writing 'ditto' as a word, as in your example, is informal and lighthearted. It would be understood to be substituting for whatever you said previously, which in your example is that the person is "good".